# lest fpc ERR (3): Notice: Undefined offset: 1

Tags: magento-1.8, cache, full-page-cache, extensions

We have 1 GB of data with the same error

2014-09-10T11:59:30+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /home/user/domains/myshop.com/public_html/.modman/Lesti_Fpc/app/code/community/Lesti/Fpc/Helper/Data.php on line 155  @ $regex = $pair[1];

What could this be? Help appreciated!

(on magento 1.8.1)

```
public function canCacheRequest()
{
    $request = Mage::app()->getRequest();
    $missParams = $this->_getMissUriParams();
    if ($request->getMethod() != 'GET') {
        return false;
    }
    foreach ($missParams as $missParam) {
        $pair = array_map('trim', explode('=', $missParam));
        $key = $pair[0];
        $regex = $pair[1]; // <==== LINE 155
        $param = $request->getParam($key);
        if ($param && preg_match($regex, $param)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: share the code of Data.php of line 155

Comment: Have you contacted Lesti?

Comment: Also, have you cleared the cache completely?

Comment: I logged on lesti site - but there was also mentioned to better maybe log @ Stack @brentwpeterson Cache completely cleared (redis)

Comment: Well...obviously `$pair[1]` is not set.  `$missParam` does not contain `=`. That's why you should always check if an array element is set before using it.  What happens if you replace that line with `$regex = (isset($pair[1])) ? $pair[1] : ''` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With thanks to @Marius

A proposed solution is to fix the line 155 by

```
$regex = (isset($pair[1])) ? $pair[1] : '';
```

or

```
if (isset($pair[1])) {   
  $regex = $pair[1]; 
} else { 
  $regex=''; 
  Mage::log('Typo in config Miss Uri Params: '. $pair[0]);
}
```

or

```
correct the typo in setting "Miss Uri Params" in config
```